# Ubuntu for Windows 10

Tags: sudo, cron, windows-10

I am new to using Ubuntu for Windows 10. I have been trying to be able to run cron on the unix but I am getting a

```
cron:can't open or create /var/run/crond.pid: Permission denied
```

This is happening while I am running it as an admin on Windows 10. However, it still would not work. How do I convince it that I am the ADMIN and that I want it to happen.
I am trying to do sudo but it is saying:

```
unable to resolve host LAPTOP-XXXX0000
```

Answer (score 0):

Bash itself needs to be run as an administrator.  You can do this by right clicking on the icon and selecting "Run as administrator", then accepting the prompt. This will allow Bash to run most commands, though it looks like there are still a lot of screwy networking features.

Comment: I am on admin but it still is throwing the unable to resolve.

Comment: @user3550783 The "real" administrator's account is hidden.  Other users are members of the administrator group with administrator privileges.  To run a command as administrator you'd have to right click on it and click `run as`.  Or change the properties of the program to run as administrator.

Comment: @L.D.James I am running it on Windows as an admin but am still getting the unable to resolve.

Comment: @user3550783 Can you describe what you did to run it as `administrator`?

Comment: I changed the Windows setting so the Ubuntu Linux to run it as admin.